# Get customer custom attribute value without loading the customer

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I'm trying to get custom customer attribute value (for attribute code abn_no) without loading the customer but not able to find any way to get it.

Is there any way to get custom customer attribute value without loading the customer?

Comment: from where you want to get the attribute value, Observer, or any custom file where customers object is available..?

Comment: i want it in my custom file. if the customer is login then i want to get attribute value of that customer, but i dont want to load the entire customer.

Comment: Have you got solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can retrieve customer custom attributes from the customer session; there's no need to load the customer every time in Magento. Please check the code below.**

```
protected $sessionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $sessionFactory,
) {
    $this->sessionFactory = $sessionFactory;
}

public function getCustomerAttribute()
{
    $customer = $this->sessionFactory->create();
    return $customer->getCustomerData()->getCustomAttribute('<Your Attribute Code>')->getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct method but you have asked the question I answered it.

***1st method:***

You can load the attribute's value by attribute's code/Id(static) with customer id(dynamic get from session). For this you have to run raw SQL for the respected attribute table like "customer_entity_varchar". Note: Attribute Id can change respected to deploy environment.

***2nd Method:*** This method is bit more correct one, you can set value in session of customer after login as you said.